# Prevent IE caching AngularJS/Restangular

Tags: angularjs, restangular

In IE, when I make an update to or destroy an item in a list, the action is successful, but the updated list/data is not returned from the server, thus the list is not being updated in the view.

I've tried the following to no avail:

```
angular.module('casemanagerApp')
.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, RestangularProvider) {

  if (!RestangularProvider.setDefaultHeaders) {
    RestangularProvider.setDefaultHeaders({});
  }

  RestangularProvider.setDefaultHeaders({'If-Modified-Since': 'Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT'});
  RestangularProvider.setDefaultHeaders({'Cache-Control': 'no-cache'});
  RestangularProvider.setDefaultHeaders({'Pragma': 'no-cache'});

  $stateProvider

  ...
});
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction for a solution to this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would recommend configuring `$httpProvider` instead of `RestangularProvider` since Restangular uses `$http` behind the scenes:

```
angular.module('casemanagerApp')
.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $httpProvider) {
  if (!$httpProvider.defaults.headers.get) {
    $httpProvider.defaults.headers.get = {};
  }

  $httpProvider.defaults.headers.get['If-Modified-Since'] = 'Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT';      
  $httpProvider.defaults.headers.get['Cache-Control'] = 'no-cache';
  $httpProvider.defaults.headers.get.Pragma = 'no-cache';
  //...

});
```

**EDIT**

I just read through the restangular.js code and the `setDefaultHeaders` function looks like it doesn't append more headers but override the default headers:

```
object.setDefaultHeaders = function(headers) {
  config.defaultHeaders = headers;
  object.defaultHeaders = config.defaultHeaders;
  return this;
};
```

This means that you were only setting the `'Pragma'` header, which may not be enough to prevent caching.

You could try doing the following:

```
RestangularProvider.setDefaultHeaders({
    'If-Modified-Since': 'Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT',
    'Cache-Control': 'no-cache',
    'Pragma': 'no-cache'
});
```

This way only Restangular calls will add the headers, and regular `http` calls won't.

Comment: Thanks boss! This worked. But why the using `RestangularProvider` work?

Comment: I thought you mentioned `RestangularProvider` wasn't working? In any case, if there are any `http` calls you're making without Restangular, now you know they won't be cached either.

Comment: Yes, `RestangularProvider` was NOT working, but when I switched to `httpProvider` per your suggestion, everything worked. So I was just asking why `RestangularProvider` wasn't working.

Comment: This will make Etags not working in chrome, which should be a 304 response.

Answer (score 0):

sharpmachine

You will have to do it manually in your controller

your view

```
<li ng-repeat="item in items">
   <a href="#" ng-click="delete(item)"></a>
</li>
```

your controller

```
$scope.delete = function(item) {
      var index = $scope.items.indexOf(item);
      if (index > -1) $scope.items.splice(index, 1);
 };
```

Comment: The problem isn't my function. It's IE caching.